# Connecting WAMP MySQL with VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, wamp

I am trying to connect WAMP MySQL with VBA. I have the tables created in the database using PHPMyAdmin. I have referenced Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library and have installed MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1 driver. I am not able to connect to mysql. My code is

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Private Sub ConnectDB()
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=127.0.0.1;" & _ ' Tried localhost too
        "DATABASE= dbtest;" & _
        "USER=root23;" & _
        "PASSWORD=pass;" & _
        "PORT=3306;"& _
        "Option=3"
End Sub
```

The error is

Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager. Data Source name not found or no default driver specified. 
All services in my WAMP are running. My http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ page opens fine. I also tried putting PORT=3306 too.

Comment: "I am not able to connect to MySql" - are you getting an error message or similar? What's happening. Your connection string looks okay.

Comment: I updated my post with the error.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be missing the port. By default, I think it's 3306; try: "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbtest;UID=root;PASSWORD=pass;Port=3306;Option=3" - that's how I have all my MySql db connections defined in VBA.

Comment: I tried with Port 3306 too. It doesn't work.

Comment: For ODBC 3.51 driver what Data Object library do you refer?

Comment: The only difference I can see is the space in the "Database= dbTest". Where did you get the ODBC drivers from? It's definitely 5.1 you are running and not 3.51? They are the only things I can think of I'm afraid as your MySql instance is obviously fine.

Comment: 3.51 works fine.. I uninstalled my ODBC drivers and downloaded the ODBC drivers 3.51 from MySQL web site and its working now.. Thanks

Comment: Heh - I haven't tested with 5.1 yet, thanks for doing this for me :-) If you don't mind, I'll move this to an answer to avoid people having to read the comments.

Comment: For sure.. and I'll mark that as accepted answer too.. and will also give an upvote.. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5727/discussion-between-ankur-and-dash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how we define our VBA connection strings for MySql:

"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=dbtest;UID=root;PASSWORD=pass;Port=3306;Option‌​=3"

From our chat, it looks like 3.51 is the version that works for you, too. It can be downloaded at the [bottom of the page here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.5.1.html)

If I get a minute I'll try a local upgrade to 5.1 and see if it's a driver specific issue. I'll comment here if I find anything.